# Spring JPA is not returning result for the next page

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I'm using JPA and trying to implement pagination for my REST calls. I'm testing using cucumber where it insert 3 records in H2 and invoke end point /getEmployee twice

1. */getEmployee?dept=science&pageNo=0&pageSize=2*
2. */getEmployee?dept=science&pageNo=1&pageSize=1*

1st invocation is working as expected and returning 2 records but 2nd invocation is not returning any result. while debugging I saw a message **Page 2 of 1 containing UNKNOWN instances** . Below is the code for my function which is getting result back from DB

```
Employees getEmployees(@RequestParam Department department
    , @RequestParam( defaultValue="0") pageNo, @RequestParam( defaultValue="0") pageSize) 
    {
      var criteria = new Criteria(pagNo, pageSize);

      employeeRepository.findBy(department, criteria);
    }

Employees findBy(Department department, Criteria criteria)
 {
   var pageable = criteria == null ? Pageable.unpaged(): PageRequest.of(criteria.PageNo(), criteria.pageSize()); 
   var pagedEmployees = employeeDAO.findByDepartment( department.toString(),pageable) 

  return pagedEmployees.getContent();  
 }


  public interface EmployeeDAO extends JPARepositiry<Employee employee, UUID>{
  List<Employee> findByDepartment(String department, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: What does the controller look? Could you add Controller code as well?